# How to replace the default arrow icons with 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons in a Material-UI pagination component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I have provided my code below. I have tried various ways but somehow, I cannot solve.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  gridPageCountSelector,
  gridPageSelector,
  gridPageSizeSelector,
  useGridApiContext,
  useGridSelector,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import Pagination from "@mui/material/Pagination";
import PaginationItem from "@mui/material/PaginationItem";
import { Stack, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  pagination: {
    "& .MuiPaginationItem-root": {
      padding: "14px",
      margin: "0", // Your custom pagination item styles here
      color: "#222124",
      fontSize: "14px",
    },
  },
}));

export default function CustomPagination() {
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();
  const page = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageSelector);
  const pageCount = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageCountSelector);
  const pageSize = gridPageSizeSelector(apiRef, gridPageSizeSelector)
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="space-between" width="100%" alignItems="center" sx={{ background: "#FAFAFA", padding: "16px" }}>
      <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" style={{ fontSize: "14px" }}>
        <div>
          Showing
        </div>
        <div>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            type="number"
            value={pageSize}
            onChange={(e) => {
              if (!isNaN(e.target.value) && e.target.value >= 1 && e.target.value <= apiRef.current.getRowsCount()) {
                apiRef.current.setPageSize(e.target.value);
              }

            }}
            sx={{
              display: 'flex', // Note the single quotes around 'flex'
              width: '68px',   // Note the single quotes around '68px'  // Note the single quotes around '8px 12px'
              alignItems: 'center', // Note the single quotes around 'center'
              gap: '8px', // Note the single quotes around '8px'
              background: "white",
              margin: "0 5px"
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          of <span style={{ fontWeight: "700" }}>{apiRef.current.getRowsCount()}</span> Results {/* Corrected method name to getRows() */}
        </div>
      </Stack>

      <Pagination
        className={classes.pagination}
        color="primary"
        variant="outlined"
        shape="rounded"
        size="small"
        page={page + 1}
        count={pageCount}
        renderItem={(props2) => <PaginationItem {...props2} disableRipple />}
        onChange={(event, value) => apiRef.current.setPage(value - 1)}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: You will need to explore `usePagination` see: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-pagination/#usepagination

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [MUI Pagination Custom icons](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-pagination/#custom-icons) documentation, you can pass custom icons for the next and previous buttons via the `next` and `previous` slots using the [`slots` prop](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/pagination-item/#PaginationItem-prop-slots) of the [`PaginationItem` component](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/pagination-item/).

For example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Pagination from "@mui/material/Pagination";
import PaginationItem from "@mui/material/PaginationItem";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import MyBackIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SubdirectoryArrowLeft";
import MyNextIcon from "@mui/icons-material/TurnRight";

export default function CustomIcons() {
  return (
    <Stack spacing={2}>
      <Pagination
        count={10}
        renderItem={(item) => (
          <PaginationItem
            slots={{ previous: MyBackIcon, next: MyNextIcon }}
            {...item}
          />
        )}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Which can produce:

[image: Custom pagination icons]

**Working Code Sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-pagination-custom-icons-xf28cs